# Не понимаю некоторые основы программирования на swift (инициализация, делегаты, протоколы, viewController)

Tags: ios, swift, объекты, делегаты, uikit

Всем привет! Я не до конца понимаю некоторые вещи, что касается инициализации, делегатов, протоколов и структур.

Я честно долго пытался самостоятельно с этим разобраться, по несколько раз пересматривал разные курсы, гуглил, писал код, перечитывал учебник, но так и не смог. Буду признателен за подробные разъяснения (потому что до этого коротких объяснений, как вы понимаете, не хватило). Я видел много примеров кода и сам могу с той или иной степенью успеха его воспроизводить, но на фундаментальном уровне у меня нет понимания, почему я это делаю.

### Инициализация

Допустим, у нас есть следующий код:

```
class Car: FourWheel {
    var name: String
    var type: String

    init(name:String, type:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

        super.init()

        changeWheel()
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что инициализаторы нужны для подготовки экземпляров класса, но в чем вообще смысл написания инициализатора, почему нельзя обойтись без него, почему нельзя просто задать значения для констант / переменных, указав их тип?

Что значит строчки типа self.name = name, почему нельзя обойтись без них?

Как мы определяем, когда нужно использовать класс, а когда структуру? (Да, я знаю, что структура – это value type, а класс – reference type). Но как на практике понимать, что нам подойдет лучше?

Когда при написании кода нужно использовать нижнее подчеркивание _ например, в этом коде:

```
struct Celsius {
    var temperatureInCelsius: Double

    init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
    temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
    }
    init(_ celsius: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = celsius
    }
}
```

### Протоколы и делегирование

Не очень понимаю, зачем они нужны. Если это шаблон для проектирования, почему этот шаблон нельзя задать через наследование? Какое практическое применение делегатов? Что значит “подписаться на делегает” и когда нам это нужно?

### view.Controller

Например, нас есть шаблон с кодом такого вида:

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Как понять, что нужно писать до viewDidLoad, что нужно писать внутри viewDidLoad, а что после него?

Comment: Вам лучше бы разбить это на два вопроса, отдельно про инициализацию, отдельно про делегирование. Вопросы хорошие, но на каждый можно написать развернутый ответ и получится очень много.

Comment: Про нижнее подчеркивание, дело вкуса. Написание в стиле `(fromKelvin kelvin: Double)` пришло в Swift из Objective C, где вы были обязаны писать в таком стиле. В Swift первый параметр у функций можно опускать и это часто делают. Что касается конструкторов и viewDidLoad, то вам лучше задать это как отдельные вопросы, т.к в первом случае речь пойдет о dependency injection, а во втором про жизненный цикл ViewController, там достаточно много рассказывать.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу протоколов и делегирования.

Постараюсь объяснить на примере реального проекта, а не сухой теории.

Итак, представьте, что у вас в проекте есть такая ситуация:

Есть некая кнопка, по нажатию на которую у вас идет запрос на удаленный сервер. Вы, выделили для таких запросов отдельный класс, назовем его `CommunicationManager`. Нажатие на кнопку вы обрабатываете во `ViewController`. Полученный ответ вам надо обработать и, допустим, поместить в какой-то UILabel на UI.

У вас получилось примерно так:

```
// ViewController
@IBAction func buttonGetDataFromRemoteServer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let communicationManager: CommunicationManager = CommunicationManager();
        let response = communicationManager.getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter: "SomeString", intParameter: 42)
        label.text = ("Hey, we've got the response: %@", response)
    }

// CommunicationManager
func getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter string: String, intParameter intp: Int) -> String {
        // Запрос занимает время
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10);
        return "Remote server response";
    }
```

Тут есть одна проблема: запрос может выполняться долго (Thread.sleep это эмулирует), соответсвенно у вас повиснет UI на все время выполнения запроса. Решение - посылать такой запрос в отдельном потоке. Получится примерно так:

```
@IBAction func buttonGetDataFromRemoteServer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let communicationManager: CommunicationManager = CommunicationManager();
        let request_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "RemoteServerRequest")
        request_queue.async {
            communicationManager.getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter: "SomeString", intParameter: 42)
        }
    }

func getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter string: String, intParameter intp: Int) -> Void {
        // do some stuff that takes time
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10);
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Упс
        }
    }
```

"Упс", потому что мы теперь связались с асинхронностью и не можем так просто сделать `return`. ViewController у нас знает про CommunicationManager, но CommunicationManager не знает про ViewController. Как решать такую проблему?

Конкретно в Swift есть минимум четыре разных способа это сделать:

Способ №1 - **Делегирование**

Создаем новый протокол:

```
@objc protocol CommunicationProtocol {

@objc optional func parseResponse (response: String)

}
```

Наследуем от него наш ViewController и CommunicationManager

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CommunicationProtocol {
    // ...

    @IBAction func buttonGetDataFromRemoteServer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let communicationManager: CommunicationManager = CommunicationManager(withDelegate: self);
        let request_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "RemoteServerRequest")
        request_queue.async {
            communicationManager.getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter: "SomeString", intParameter: 42)
        }
    }

    func parseResponse (response: String) {
        label.text = ("Hey, we've got the response: %@", response)
    }

class CommunicationManager: NSObject, CommunicationProtocol {

    var delegate: CommunicationProtocol

    init(withDelegate delegate: CommunicationProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }

    func getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter string: String, intParameter intp: Int) -> Void {
        // do some stuff that takes time
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10);
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate.parseResponse!(response: "Remote server response")
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, у вас CommunicationManager *поручает* (собственно слово delegate и значит поручать) ViewController-у выполнить какой-то метод. При этом CommunicationManager по прежнему не имеет прямой ссылки на ViewController, т.е архитектуру мы не нарушаем.

Способ №2 - **Callback**.

В реальных проектах для такой задачи вы скорее всего будете использовать не делегат, а callback.

Подход похожий, только в функциональном стиле, с использованием замыканий, а не протокола.

```
@IBAction func buttonGetDataFromRemoteServer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let communicationManager: CommunicationManager = CommunicationManager();
    let request_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "RemoteServerRequest")

    request_queue.async {
        communicationManager.getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter: "SomeString", intParameter: 42, completion: { (response) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                label.text = ("Hey, we've got the response: %@", response)
            }
        })
    }
}

func getSomeDataFromRemoteServer(stringParameter string: String, intParameter intp: Int, completion: @escaping ((_ response: String) -> Void)) -> Void {
        // do some stuff that takes time
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10);
        completion("Remote server response");
    }
```

Есть еще два способа сделать это - воспользоваться **NotificationCenter** либо **Key-Value-Observation**.

Оба подхода - частный случай шаблона Observer. В первой случае вы слушаете со стороны ViewController определенно событие (`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver`), которое посылается из CommunicationManager через `NotificationCenter.default.post`.

Во втором вы следите за изменением состояния определенного свойства.

По личному опыту, в реальных проектах используются в основном callback-и и NotificationCenter, делегирование значительно меньше (хотя иногда без него не обойтись). KVO способ сильно на любителя с кучей подводных камней, я бы его не рекомендовал. Если нравится использовать шаблон Observer, посмотрите в сторону библиотеки RxSwift.

---

Помимо делегирования протоколы могут использоваться еще в нескольких ситуациях.

Классический случай - вам нужно, чтобы несколько классов реализовывали одни и те же методы, но каждый со своей реализацией. Реальным примером может служить таблица UITableViewController. Любая таблица должна реализовывать методы, отвечающие за число секций, ячеек, содержимое этих ячеек и взаимодействие с ними. Однако для каждой таблицы реализация будет своя.

От себя еще могу добавить, что протоколы в реальных проектах нужны, если вы пишите юнит-тесты с использованием mock и fake объектов.

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен за ответ, но, к сожалению, мне он показался из такого количества сложного кода слишком непонятным

Comment: @NikitaAbleyev Советую пройтись по основам iOS и Swift например используя эти материалы, т.к. ответ довольно исчерпывающий о делегатах:   
  
1) [SwiftBook](https://swiftbook.ru)  
2) [Видео курс по iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_f2mkySKU8&list=PL6WGVnrRLVRfWriSvjWz0OCxO-j7PAvio)