# Как работает эта часть кода в функции?

Tags: swift, функции

Выделил звездочками ту часть кода, которая мне не ясна.

```
func makeIncrementer() -> **((Int) -> Int)** {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

Comment: Это называется замыкание. В реальных проектах вы столкнетесь с этим, когда будете работать с асинхронными функциями. Я подробно объяснял вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959605/Не-понимаю-некоторые-основы-программирования-на-swift-инициализация-делегаты/959855#959855) (часть про Callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323569/what-does-the-type-int-int-mean-in-swift

Это показывает, какой тип данных функция принимает и какой возвращает

То есть данная функция должна получить `Int` и вернуть также `Int`

Comment: Неверно. Данная функция (`makeIncrementer`) аргументов не принимает (первая, пустая пара скобок) и возвращает функцию. А возвращаемая функция, какой бы она не была, уже принимает Int и возвращает Int .

Answer (score 1):

Выделенная часть — это тип значения, возвращаемого функцией. В вашем случае этот тип — тоже функция:

```
((список_типов_параметров) -> возвращаемый_тип)
```

В Swift функции можно присваивать переменным и возвращать из функций, как любые другие значения. В данном случае `makeIncrementer()` возвращает другую функцию, принимающую `Int` и возвращающую `Int`.